# ReactJS msw data response for each test weird overlap

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, msw

I have this code to mock the data response from the API but somehow, the 2nd test is always overwritten by the first one and leads to a test failure. Even using `res.once` not working.

```js
// ...import section

test('Should component render successfully', () => {
    server.use(
      rest.get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/api/discount`,
        (req, res, ctx) => {
          return res(ctx.status(200), ctx.json({ data: DiscountMockData.vouchers[0] }));
        }
      )
    );
    
    render(<MyComponent />);
    
    expect(screen.getByTestId('result')).toBeInTheDocumment();
});

test('Should component render failed because of API response', () => {
    server.use(
      rest.get(
        `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_ENDPOINT}/api/discount`,
        (req, res, ctx) => {
          return res(ctx.status(400), ctx.json({}));
        }
      )
    );
    
    render(<MyComponent />);
    
    expect(screen.getByTestId('error')).toBeInTheDocumment();
})
```

Somehow, the `Should component render failed because of API response` always failed because the response is success on the first test, if I remove the first test then the 2nd is working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import { cleanup } from "@testing-library/react";
import { setupServer } from "msw/node";


const handlers = [
  rest.get(URL, (req, res, ctx) => {
    // ...
    return response;
  }),
  // so on ...
];
const server = setupServer(...handlers);


// Cleanup after each test case
afterEach(() => {
  cleanup();
  server.resetHandlers();
});


afterAll(() => {
  server.close();
});
```

Comment: I will try and mark your answer if things working, thanks for your time.